# C++ typedef a std::pair and then use the typedef to declare a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, typedef, std-pair

Let's say I have this typedef

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, uint32_t> MyType;
```

Then, if I also want to create a map using MyType, how do I do it?

I don't want to re-type the two types in the pair like:

```
map<std::string, uint32_t> myMap;
```

I want something like:

```
map<MyType's first type, MyType's second type> myMap;
```

Is there a way to do it like that using my typedef MyType instead of re-typing the types?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply...

```
std::map<MyType::first_type, MyType::second_type> myMap;
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair

Sample program at <kbd>[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c593e9b441eba5aa)</kbd>

Comment: Ah that's how you use member types on the type.. I tried using dot and arrow operators and didn't work...lol Thank you very much. (will need to wait for 2 min to accept it as answer)

Comment: But it does depend on `MyType` being a std::pair.  If this is a simplified version of the real problem the OP will need to ask another question (and they may well be out of luck).  The language doesn't provide a general way to introspect typedefs, one has to rely on the typedef'ed type to provide a mechanism for that.

Comment: @MartinBonner My problem is actually the simple pair case. :)

Comment: Just for the record, the map will not contain such pairs then! Instead, it will contain `pair<string const,uint32_t>`, because the first one (the key) is stored as constant.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to be doing this with a lot of different types, you can set up an *alias declaration*.

```
template <typename T>
using pair_map = std::map< typename T::first_type, typename T::second_type>;

typedef std::pair<std::string, int> MyType;

pair_map<MyType> my_map;
```

This requires at least c++11.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a pair it amounts to a single attribute. Pair is like a derived data type. When you are using a pair in map, it is considered as a key or a value based on your declaration. But the first and second objects of a pair can't be the key and values in a map. You can use typedef for both the data types separately and use the shortcuts or as mentioned in the previous answer. Instead of writing "std::" repeatedly, You can use 
**using namespace std;** Thanks.

Comment: You *can* use `using namespace std;`, but just because you can, doesn't mean it is a good idea..  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you for the information @MartinBonner